# Group Theory about proving there exists m,n such that $(x ∗ y)^{−1}= y^m ∗ x^n$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I have been trying to solve this question from a past exam for a very long time but don't know how to go about it. I tried making the LHS of the equation equal the identity but that didn't go far.

Any help is appreciated.

Let $(G, ∗, I)$ be a group. Let $x, y ∈ G$ both have finite order. Prove that there exist $m, n ≥ 0$ such that $(x ∗ y)^{−1}= y^m ∗ x^n$.

Comment: Do you know of a very classic way of writing $ (xy)^{-1} $ in terms of $ x^{-1} $ and $ y^{-1} $?

Comment: Expanding the bracket?

Comment: what about $x*y*y^m*x^n$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $x,y$ is of finite order, there exists some positive integer $k,l$ such that $x^k=y^l=id$. Now note that $(x*y)^{-1}=y^{-1}*x^{-1}=y^{l-1}*x^{k-1}$.

Comment: I am a little bit confused about y^{l-1}*x^{k-1}. How did you get this?

Comment: @OptOut $y^l=id$, multiply both sides by $y^{-1}$ to see $y^{l-1}=y^{-1}$. The same for $x^{k-1}=x^{-1}$.